# Keep scroll position in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a table with fixed header and scrollable body. The issue is - if I scroll down or scroll left the body and after adding new row the scroll position of tbody resets in IE. In other browsers all works fine.

For do tbody scrollable I use styles display:block and positon:fixed. I use "fixed" because it works for IE for scrolling.

See simple example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nezW/26/) (click on row to add new one)

Comment: I saw that in IE9 after adding new row after current row the scroll position has not resets. But if I add new row after last row the scroll position has resets. In IE8 scroll position has been reset in both case.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried in IE8. The scroll position does not reset if to replace the `tbody.find("tr").live()` with `tbody.find("tr").bind()`. Try to use `if($.browser.msie)` condition to use it in IE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not resolve my problem in full.